# Convert part of List<string> to byte[]

Tags: c#, list, arrays

```
List<string> K = new List<string>();
byte[] tmp = K[i >> 3].SelectMany(s => Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
```

I tying to convert, but there is an error:

*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.Encoding.GetString(byte[])' has some invalid arguments*

How correctly do this?

Comment: Your code and your error don't match. You're not calling `GetString` at all in your sample code, which makes me think you're not actually posting the code you're running.

Comment: Additionally, your example is too complex and hides the real problem. Your `K[i >> 3]` call returns a `string`, so you can simplify it by just calling `myString.SelectMany(s=> ,,,)`, which might help you see the problem yourself.

Comment: You need a two dimensional array byte[,] and you have only a one dimensional array.  Each string will create a byte[] and a List<> object contains multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you expect the call to `K[i >> 3]` to do. Your title says "convert part of a List", but what it does is simply return *one* string out of your `List<string>`.

Next, you call `SelectMany()` on that string. Since `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, the `SelectMany` call tries to call `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` on each `char` in the string and return the resulting `byte[]` returned from each call into a combined `IEnumerable<byte>`. This fails, because `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` expects a *string* parameter, not a *char*.

Based on your title, I expect that you expected `K[i >> 3]` to return an `IEnumerable<string>` containing a subset of your original `List<string>`. If it did, your code would make sense - `SelectMany` would pass each string in the subset to `GetBytes`, which would return a `byte[]`, which would be concatenated to a larger `IEnumerable<byte>` containing the bytes for all the strings in the subset. But you need to fix your root cause, the subset-selection, for that to work.